# object shorthand syntax in typescript compiler

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, tsc

```js
interface o {
  name: string
}
const func = (obj: o): boolean => true

// this should throw error message.(or warning message at least, but it doesn't)
func({ name })
```

`name` is undefined in the code I wrote, so `func({ name })` should throw an error I think. Is this intended?
Can I fix this with eslint or tsc config?

---

**edit**: this isn't a duplicate
I'm in **node** and Global.name is undefined.
It seems `tsc` thinks `name` is string though.

my tsconfig.json:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                               
  "compilerOptions": {                                                                                                                                                          
     "experimentalDecorators": true,                                                                                                                                             
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                                                                                                                                              
     "skipLibCheck" : true,                                                                                                                                                      
     "rootDir": "./src",                                                                                                                                                         
     "outDir": "./src/js"                                                                                                                                                        
   }                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it come from global object

Comment: Not really a duplicate IMO. This is about how TypeScript behaves in this instance. @soonoo Take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18433)

Comment: @lukasgeiter It says 'do not use `name`'. What a ridiculous solution. HAHA.

Comment: At least there's this the [`no-restricted-globals`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals) ESLint rule which you should be able to use for this.

Comment: Do you mean that it should cause a *compile error*? If it doesn't, does it at least throw a *runtime error*? If not, what is the value when you do `console.log(name, typeof name)`?

Comment: You need to show the .tsconfig settings. It throws a compile error for me when I don't tell it to assume a browser environment.

Comment: @Bergi tsc compiles above code without error/warning and compiled js code throws `ReferenceError` since `name` isn't in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript declares a global called `name` in `lib.dom.d.ts` because of [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

`name` is declared with type `never` but that doesn't prevent it from being an issue. There is a discussion on Github on changing it's type to `void` in which case there would be an error in your example. A workaround is to configure ESLint with the rule [`no-restricted-globals`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals).

---

However, since you're compiling for Node.js, there is actually a much better solution. Because you don't need any type definitions for DOM APIs it's best to not include `lib.dom.d.ts` at all.

You can do this by specifying the [`lib` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) explicitly in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "ES5"
        ]
    }
}
```

> **Note:** the exact value for `lib` you'll need depends on your project. See the [compiler options documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for all available values and the defaults for different targets